# 型の変換について

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, xcode7

```
var publicKeyBits = Unmanaged<AnyObject>?()
SecItemCopyMatching(queryAttrs, &publicKeyBits)
```

## エラー内容

> Cannot convert value of type 'Unmanaged?' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

どうやったら使えるようになるでしょうか。

## 追記

```
var result: Unmanaged<AnyObject>?
let pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?> = UnsafeMutablePointer((result?.toOpaque())!)
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(queryAttrs, pointer)
```

こう書き換えることでエラーはなくなりましたが、

> Thread1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP. subcode0x0)

実行した際にこういうエラーが出ました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cの関数に渡す時は、`AnyObject?`に`&`をつけると、`UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>`として扱ってくれます。

```
let SecClassValue       = kSecClass     as NSString
let SecReturnRefValue   = kSecReturnRef as NSString
let query: NSMutableDictionary = [
    SecClassValue       : kSecClassCertificate,
    SecReturnRefValue   : kCFBooleanTrue,
    // append query
]
var result: AnyObject?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &result)
if status == errSecSuccess {
    // do something
}
```

公式リファレンス using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C の [Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17)を参照してみてください。